# Visualize 3D data as heatmap

Tags: matlab, visualization, mask, heatmap

I have a matrix (brain map) **Y** with the dimensions `53x63x46`. Most of the values are NaN but some range from -.07 to 1.5. I would like to visualize this as a heat map. Could anyone please help me how to visualize this? It may also be helpful to present the image as 2D and just show the relevant slices (i.e., important locations).

Update: I found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/251810-shifting-a-heat-map-upwards-along-the-z-axis) so I thought I'd try to move the images along the x axis but it doesn't look quite right.

```
atX=20;
surf(atX * ones(size(Y,2),size(Y,3)),'CData',Y(:,:,atX),'FaceColor','TextureMap');
```

Comment: Function imagesc - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html For the 2D - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/59463-plot-heatmap-with-3-variables